# Format ttest output by r for tex

Tags: r, latex

For formatting my regression outputs generated by R for Tex, I use stargazer. However this command doesn't work for a simple t.test ouput (% Error: Unrecognized object type). I know the "xtable" and "schoRsch" packages, however there is some loss of information, when applying these two. Does anyone know another command? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Give [Pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) a try, it’s an all round good table formatting package for R, and supports the `t.test` result type. I’m not sure whether it leaves out too much information for your taste, though.

```
result = t.test(…)
pander(result)
```

Pander produces Markdown rather than LaTeX tables, so the result needs to be transformed into LaTeX using pandoc.

Alternatively, you can use [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) to generate a regular table form your `t.test` result, and stargaze that:

```
stargazer(tidy(result))
```

Broom also knows the `glance` function for a reduced output, however, for `t.test` the result is the same.

---

Extending `stargazer` for other types is effectively not possible, since everything is hard-coded in the function. The only thing you can do is put the data of interest into a `data.frame` and pass that to `stargazer`. You may want to play with this approach a bit. Here’s a basic example of what you could do:

```
stargazer_htest = function (data, ...) {
    summary = data.frame(`Test statistic` = data$statistic,
                         DF = data$parameter,
                         `p value` = data$p.value,
                         `Alternative hypothesis` = data$alternative,
                         check.names = FALSE)
    stargazer(summary, flip = TRUE, summary = FALSE,
              notes = paste(data$method, data$data.name, sep = ': '), ...)
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
stargazer_htest(t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep))
```

To produce the following output:

[image: screenshot]

… Note the completely wonky alignment and the wrong formatting of negative numbers. I gave up trying to get this to work: I would suggest dropping stargazer, it doesn’t like customisation.

In summary, the stargazer output isn’t nearly as “beautiful” or “easy to use” as they claim: their table formatting is cluttered and runs afoul of best practices for table formatting (which are summarised in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs?lang=en) package documentation). The function is impossible to customise meaningfully for own types and instead offers a jungle of parameters. Oh, and despite their claim of supporting “a large number of models”, they don’t even support the base R hypothesis tests.

At the risk of sounding divisive, stargazer is a pretty terrible package.

Comment: Thank you very much Konrad for your answer! stargazer(tidy(result)) doesn't work at all. pander(result) produces an acceptable table, however it drops the mean  and confidence intervals, which I want to keep.

Comment: What does “doesn’t work at all” mean? It does produce a table for me. If the format isn’t right for you then you can also try `stargazer(coefficients(summary(result)))`. In fact, that’s probably the most helpful output of them all …

Comment: Thank you again for your answer Konrad. You are right, stargazer(tidy(result)) works, but the table was not suitable for my purpose. Thank you for the update. I think I'm missing sth, because this time, the code really doesn't work. If I use the example from r     `t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep)`    and put it in `stargazer(coefficients(summary(t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep))))` I don't get an output. What am I missing here? I am looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @HausladenCarina Apologies, you’re right. I accidentally ran `lm` in my toy example instead of `t.test`. I’ve updated my answer with some more attempts. But my take-away is this: stargazer is terrible, don’t use it.