# Is it possible to add a custom column in stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer

I would like to add an additional column to my variable names so that I may identify the exact parameters the labels are referring to. I realize that I don't need to add a custom column, but I think it would like nicer if I could.  Preferably, the custom column would be have the title "Parameters", to the left of the model numbers. Is this possible? Here is some baseline code:

```
library(stargazer)
data <- stargazer(attitude)
linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning
              + raises + critical, data=attitude)
linear.2 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning, data=attitude)
stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, type = "text",
          column.labels = c("model 1", "model 2"),
          covariate.labels = c("Complaints ($\\alpha$)",
                               "Privileges ($\\beta$)",
                               "Learning ($\\gamma$)",
                               "Raises ($\\delta$)",
                               "Critical ($\\epsilon$)",
                               "Intercept"
          ))
```

ideally, i would like to have something like this:

Comment: Since there’s no answer here yet I’ll point you to an old answer I’ve written: [Stargazer is terrible, don’t use it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32035526/1968). It produces terrible formatting, offers next to no customisation and has a very poor API. Use Pander or something similar instead.

Answer (score -3):

Use `add.lines` (refer documentation)

```
stargazer(output, output2, type = "html", add.lines = list(c("Fixed effects?", "No", "No"),c("Results believable?", "Maybe", "Try again later")))
```

You can also check the link [here](https://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/#add-a-custom-row-to-the-reported-statistics)

Comment: I'm sorry but this adds a new row not a new column.