# Generate LaTeX code for a table corresponding to a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which the element at index (i,j) is the sample mean obtained under method j and during time period i. I have another data frame which contains the standard errors of the corresponding sample means. I can convert either data frame to LaTeX table using the stargazer package but what I would like to do is to create a single LaTeX table using both data frames such that the element at index (i,j) of this table should contain the corresponding sample mean right above the standard error of this mean in parentheses. Obviously, I want to avoid manual data entry as much as possible.

Comment: [Stargazer is pure garbage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32035526/1968). I would recommend using literally *anything* else. For more concrete advice, you can join the tables in R and then use `knitr::kable` or “xtable”. The most versatile option (but a bit indirect, going R–Markdown–LaTeX) is to use [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) to generate a Markdown table, and then generate a LaTeX document from that (using pandoc, but the process is automated).

Comment: let's say your table is this `tabla1 <- with(data, table(yoprcor3, sexo))`then `kable(tabla1)`works for knit pdf or knit html