# R :How to get a proper latex regression table from a dataframe?

Tags: r, latex, linear-regression, stargazer, texreg

Consider the following example

```
inds <- c('var1','','var2','')
model1 <- c(10.2,0.00,0.02,0.3)
model2 <- c(11.2,0.01,0.02,0.023)

df = df=data.frame(inds,model1,model2)
df
 inds model1 model2
 var1  10.20 11.200
        0.00  0.010
 var2   0.02  0.020
        0.30  0.023
```

Here you have the output of a custom regression model with coefficients and P-values (I actually can show any other statistics if I need to, say, the standard errors of the coefficients).

There are two variables, `var1` and `var2`.

For instance, in model1, `var1` comes with a coefficient of `10.2` and a P-value of `0.00` while `var2` has a coefficient of `0.02` and a P-value of `0.30`.

Is there a package that handle these (custom) tables automatically and can create a neat Latex table with stars for significance?

Thanks!

Comment: Up front: Don’t use Stargazer. [It’s terrible.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32035526/1968) And it cannot be customised at all.

Comment: thanks @KonradRudolph. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for suggestions, I use the package ‹pander› in combination with ‹knitr› for all my table typesetting needs. However, I manually post-process the result to produce tables that follow the convention laid out in the [‹booktabs› documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf). No easy to use solution, I’m afraid.

Comment: cant we use your pander solution in that case? would the code be hard to write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `texreg`.

Note that `texreg` >= 1.36.18 is required.

The information you are providing in the data frame (coefs and p-values) could be arranged in arbitrary ways in a data frame. Therefore we need to write code that selects these data from the appropriate places in the data frame and uses them to create a `texreg` object. As you are requesting a generic (and presumably re-usable) solution, we should wrap the code in a re-usable function. I'll call this function `extractFromDataFrame`. So here is the function, which extracts the information from the data frame and creates a list of `texreg` objects for the different models:

```
require("texreg")

extractFromDataFrame <- function (dataFrame) {
  coef.row.indices <- seq(1, nrow(dataFrame) - 1, 2)
  pval.row.indices <- seq(2, nrow(dataFrame), 2)
  texregObjects <- list()
  for (i in 2:ncol(dataFrame)) {
    coefs <- dataFrame[coef.row.indices, i]
    coefnames <- as.character(dataFrame[coef.row.indices, 1])
    pvalues <- dataFrame[pval.row.indices, i]
    tr <- createTexreg(coef = coefs, coef.names = coefnames, pvalues = pvalues)
    texregObjects[i - 1] <- list(tr)
  }
  return(texregObjects)
}
```

In this function, we first define in which rows of the data frame the coefficients are stored and in which rows the p-values are stored. Then we created an empty list in which we stored the `texreg` objects. We iterate through all columns but the first as the first one contains only the labels. In each of these model columns, we save the coefficients, their names, and the p-values, and then we hand them over to the `createTexreg` constructor, which is a function that creates a `texreg` object for us based on the data. We add the `texreg` object to the list. In the end, we return the list of `texreg` objects.

We can now apply the function to any data frame that looks like the one provided in the question, with arbitrary numbers of columns (> 1). In this case, after applying the function to the `df` object, we may want to print the contents of the list if we want to make sure that we did everything right:

```
tr <- extractFromDataFrame(df)
tr
```

And indeed, the results contain the relevant data:

```
[[1]]

No standard errors were defined for this texreg object.
No decimal places were defined for the GOF statistics.

     coef.   p
var1 10.20 0.0
var2  0.02 0.3

No GOF block defined.

[[2]]

No standard errors were defined for this texreg object.
No decimal places were defined for the GOF statistics.

     coef.     p
var1 11.20 0.010
var2  0.02 0.023

No GOF block defined.
```

Now we can simply hand the list of `texreg` objects over to `screenreg`, e.g., `screenreg(tr)`, with the following result:

```
========================
      Model 1    Model 2
------------------------
var1  10.20 ***  11.20 *
var2   0.02       0.02 *
========================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Or to `htmlreg` for creating an HTML table. Or, as requested in the original question, to `texreg` for creating a LaTeX table. The output of `texreg(tr, single.row = TRUE)` looks like this:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c }
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 \\
\hline
var1 & $10.20^{***}$ & $11.20^{*}$ \\
var2 & $0.02$        & $0.02^{*}$  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

This solution can be modified to accommodate standard errors, confidence intervals, or goodness-of-fit statistics.

Various `texreg` arguments can be used to customize the output, including the use of the `booktabs` package or decimal alignment via `dcolumn`, for example.

Please note that you should not call your data frame `df` because that object name is already defined in the `stats` package.

Comment: what can I say? Amazing!!