# Using nest and tidy to create formatted html regression output in RMarkdown

Tags: r, logistic-regression, tidyr, stargazer, export-to-html

I have used `tidyr::nest` to run a series of logistic regression models with different dependent variables. I want to output the results as a single html table in RMarkdown with each model as a column and the rows as exponentiated coefficients with 99% CIs. I cannot figure out the workflow between `nest`, `tidy`, and a table-rendering package like `stargazer` to get this to work. If I `unnest` my `tidy` output and pass it to `stargazer`, or if I just try to pass the `nest`ed output (the variable in the nested data frame called "model" below) to `stargazer` directly, I get no output. I would prefer to use the `tidy` output anyway because of the exponentiated coefficients and 99% CIs. I essentially need [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) to go one step farther and explain how to use the output of `nest` and `tidy` to create formatted regression tables. I also looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027811/formatted-latex-regression-tables-with-multiple-models-from-broom-output), but I find it hard to believe that there isn't an easier way to do this that I am just missing.

Sample data, along with my general approach to running the models:

```
id <- 1:2000
gender <- sample(0:1, 2000, replace = T)
age <- sample(17:64, 2000, replace = T)
race <- sample(0:1, 2000, replace = T)
cond_a <- sample(0:1, 2000, replace = T)
cond_b <- sample(0:1, 2000, replace = T)
cond_c <- sample(0:1, 2000, replace = T)
cond_d <- sample(0:1, 2000, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(id, gender, age, race, cond_a, cond_b, cond_c, cond_d)

df %>% gather(c(cond_a, cond_b, cond_c, cond_d), key = "condition", value = "case") %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~glm(case ~ gender + age + race, family = "binomial", data = .)),
         tidy = map(model, tidy, exponentiate = T, conf.int = T, conf.level = 0.99))
```

Comment: i don't get your question.. you can just unnest the tidy part and you get the table of regression coefficients?

Comment: Sorry, I am struggling to figure out how to explain my problem. I edited the post to try to be clearer about where things are breaking down for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I get it correct, essentially you pass the lm objects and the confidence interval separately into `stargazer`, using [this answer from your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027811/formatted-latex-regression-tables-with-multiple-models-from-broom-output/52028695#52028695).

You can read the [stargazer help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer) for how to input for example custom ci would require:

> ci.custom: a list of two-column numeric matrices that will replace the
> default confidence intervals for each model. The first and
> second columns represent the lower and the upper bounds,
> respectively. Matched by element names.

So in your case, it's a little bit more work, we store the results first.

```
result = df %>% gather(c(cond_a, cond_b, cond_c, cond_d), key = "condition", value = "case") %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~glm(case ~ gender + age + race, family = "binomial", data = .)),
         tidy = map(model, tidy, exponentiate = T, conf.int = T, conf.level = 0.99))

tidy_model = result$tidy
fit = result$model
```

Then pull out CI and coefficients:

```
CI = lapply(tidy_model,function(i)as.matrix(i[,c("conf.low","conf.high")]))
Coef = lapply(tidy_model,"[[","estimate")
```

Then apply `stargazer`:

```
stargazer(fit, type = "text", 
  coef = Coef,
  ci.custom = CI)


=============================================================================
                                      Dependent variable:                    
                  -----------------------------------------------------------
                                             case                            
                       (1)            (2)            (3)            (4)      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
gender               0.996***       1.182***       1.196***       0.921***   
                  (0.790, 1.254) (0.938, 1.489) (0.950, 1.508) (0.731, 1.161)
                                                                             
age                  1.004***       1.001***       0.999***       1.005***   
                  (0.995, 1.012) (0.993, 1.009) (0.990, 1.007) (0.996, 1.013)
                                                                             
race                 0.911***       0.895***       0.944***       1.213***   
                  (0.724, 1.148) (0.711, 1.128) (0.749, 1.189) (0.963, 1.529)
                                                                             
Constant             0.919***       0.997***       0.959***       0.761***   
                  (0.623, 1.356) (0.676, 1.472) (0.649, 1.415) (0.515, 1.123)
                                                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations          2,000          2,000          2,000          2,000     
Log Likelihood      -1,385.107     -1,382.664     -1,383.411     -1,382.272  
Akaike Inf. Crit.   2,778.215      2,773.329      2,774.821      2,772.544   
=============================================================================
Note:                                             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: this is incredibly helpful, thank you. I guess I am surprised that there is not a tidyverse way of exporting the output from models stored in a nested data frame to regression tables. I am not wedded to stargazer, it just has worked a bit better for me than others I've tried, which have included gtsummary, kable, and jtools::export_summs. jtools::export_summs gives me the right coefficients, etc, but it can only work with model objects themselves, which don't seem to be preserved anywhere in the nested data frame.

Comment: in your case, you need something more custom, and tidy works with long format data, so not the most straightforward i would guess. I don't work much with Rmarkdown or regression output, so not the best person to comment on how to use tidy with these