# How to tabulate the results of a model with multiple LHS in R?

Tags: r, stargazer, texreg, mlm

When multiple regressions have the same RHS, it can be more efficient to run them in one go (see [Fitting a linear model with multiple LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262534/fitting-a-linear-model-with-multiple-lhs/39279431#39279431)). E.g., using `lm` and `felm` :

```
library(lfe)

lm.fit.m <- lm(cbind(mpg, cyl) ~ gear, mtcars)
fe.fit.m <- felm(cbind(mpg, cyl) ~ gear | vs, mtcars)
```

I am looking to produce a table of the results with coefficients, standard errors, and model and sample summary stats reported. Is there a wrapper out there for that?

### Update: Failed Attempts

In the usual case with one LHS var, there are plenty of options.

```
lm.fit.s <- list(lm(mpg ~ gear, mtcars), lm(cyl ~ gear, mtcars))
fe.fit.s <- list(felm(mpg ~ gear | vs, mtcars), felm(cyl ~ gear | vs, mtcars))
```

#### Stargazer

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(lm.fit.s, fe.fit.s, type = "text")
```

Gives:

```
========================================================================================
                                               Dependent variable:                      
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------
                               mpg             cyl             mpg             cyl      
                               OLS             OLS            felm            felm      
                               (1)             (2)             (3)             (4)      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gear                        3.923***        -1.193***       2.930***        -0.823***   
                             (1.308)         (0.385)         (1.023)         (0.221)    

Constant                      5.623         10.585***                                   
                             (4.916)         (1.445)                                    

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Observations                   32              32              32              32       
R2                            0.231           0.243           0.564           0.768     
Adjusted R2                   0.205           0.217           0.534           0.752     
Residual Std. Error      5.374 (df = 30) 1.580 (df = 30) 4.114 (df = 29) 0.889 (df = 29)
F Statistic (df = 1; 30)    8.995***        9.617***                                    
========================================================================================
Note:                                                        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

But `stargazer` doesn't seem to currently support multi-LHS models.

```
> stargazer(lm.fit.m)
Error in if (.global.coefficient.variables[i] %in% .global.intercept.strings) { : 
  argument is of length zero
> stargazer(fe.fit.m)
Error in summary.felm(object.name) : 
  Please specify lhs=[one of cbind(mpg, cyl).mpg,cbind(mpg, cyl).cyl]
```

#### Texreg

```
library(texreg)
texreg::screenreg(c(lm.fit.s, fe.fit.s))
```

Gives:

```
===============================================================
                       Model 1   Model 2    Model 3   Model 4  
---------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)             5.62     10.59 ***                     
                       (4.92)    (1.45)                        
gear                    3.92 **  -1.19 **    2.93 **  -0.82 ***
                       (1.31)    (0.38)     (1.02)    (0.22)   
---------------------------------------------------------------
R^2                     0.23      0.24                         
Adj. R^2                0.21      0.22                         
Num. obs.              32        32         32        32       
RMSE                    5.37      1.58                         
R^2 (full model)                             0.56      0.77    
R^2 (proj model)                             0.22      0.32    
Adj. R^2 (full model)                        0.53      0.75    
Adj. R^2 (proj model)                        0.17      0.28    
===============================================================
*** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

But for multi-LHS if too fails:

```
> texreg::screenreg(lm.fit.m)
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “texreg” object: 1: invalid object for slot "coef.names" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "character"
invalid class “texreg” object: 2: invalid object for slot "coef" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "numeric"
invalid class “texreg” object: 3: invalid object for slot "se" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "numeric"
invalid class “texreg” object: 4: invalid object for slot "pvalues" in class "texreg": got class "NULL", should be or extend class "numeric"
> texreg::screenreg(fe.fit.m)
Error in summary.felm(model) : 
  Please specify lhs=[one of cbind(mpg, cyl).mpg,cbind(mpg, cyl).cyl]
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on your expected output, and the errors you are encountering?

Comment: @Chris I've updated the question to specify the expected output and errors

Comment: Rule of thumb: [Never use stargazer, it’s utter rubbish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035526/1968). Try [texreg](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg), by all accounts it’s excellent.

Comment: @KonradRudolph great to learn about `texreg` but it doesn't seem to be working in this case